# Accessing Properties of elements in a Data Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How can one access the properties of the Textblock(txtlink) in the below XAML code from c#? Referencing txtlink. doesn't work and it results in an error

> The name txtlink doesn't exist in the current context

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentRss.Channel.NewsItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtlink"  Text="{Binding Link}" Background="Black" Foreground="#FFD1DA0B"/>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Use `SelectedItem` binding, then you will have access to the selected item. From there you can access the `Link` property.

Comment: There is one TextBlock per row of the ListBox created? Which one do you need access to? And when do you need access to it?

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Use SelectedItem binding, then you will have access to the selected item. From there you can access the Link property.
xaml:

```
<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentRss.Channel.NewsItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNewsItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtlink"  Text="{Binding Link}" Background="Black" Foreground="#FFD1DA0B"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and in your ViewModel:

```
public NewsItem SelectedNewsItem {get;set;}//INPC when it is being set check for null and then process the selected item.
```